# Why does non-thread safe counter in Java always return the correct value?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm trying to simulate a non-thread safe counter class by incrementing the count in an executor service task and using countdown latches to wait for all threads to start and then stop before reading the value in the main thread.

The issue is that when I run it the System.out at the end always returns 10 as the correct count value. I was expecting to see some other value when I run this as the 10 threads may see different values.

My code is below. Any idea what is happening here? I'm running it in Java 17 and from Intellij IDEA.

Counter.java

```
public class Counter {

    private int counter = 0;

    public void incrementCounter() {
        counter += 1;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(10);
        CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(10);
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    startSignal.countDown();
                    startSignal.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                counter.incrementCounter();
                doneSignal.countDown();
            });
        }

        doneSignal.await();
        System.out.println("Finished: " + counter.getCounter());
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the final value be different if all threads do the same every time and you always wait for all thread to finish?

Comment: I thought the problem here would be thread visibility. For example thread A may increment counter but thread B may still see 0 because the change isn't visible to that thread. I thought in order to make this thread safe the counter field should be marked as volatile so all threads see the latest update?

Comment: As @biziclop already answered, there is *no guarantee* that it will break, only a chance. Try incrementing the counter multiple times (say 10 or 100) in each task, that would increase the likelyhood of something "going wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth remembering that just because something isn't synchronised correctly, it could still perform correctly under some circumstances, it just isn't **guaranteed** to do so in every situation, on every JVM, on every hardware.

In other words, there is no reverse guarantee, optimisers for example are free to decide your code can be replaced at little to no cost with a correctly synchronised implementation.

(Whether that is what's actually happening here isn't obvious to me at first glance.)

Comment: I think one reason why things don't "go wrong" here is because each tread only reads and writes the variable exactly once and thus is unlikely to have it already cached. But as you said: that's far from being a guarantee for it to always work.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, that's a good point, running thousands of passes might get it to break.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. I tried incrementing the counter 1000 times for each task as mentioned and I get varying counts at the end.